# Castle 2.5.3 .NET 4 failing trying to read a config file over UNC

Tags: castle-windsor

We've recently upgraded to 2.5.3 of Castle Windsor in order to take advantage of the code access mechanism around full and partial trust when trying to run an exe over UNC.  We are getting the following error:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for castle: Request failed. 
(\\server\dev\oursolution.VS2010Clean\OurApp\bin\x86\Release\OurApp.exe.Config
line 10) ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.

    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)

    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)

    at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)

    at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)

    at
System.Configuration.TypeUtil.CreateInstanceWithReflectionPermission(Type type)

    at
System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord
configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)

    at
System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord
configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)

    at
System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord
factoryRecord)

    at
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String
configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)

    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

    at
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String
configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere)

    at
System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String
configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object&
resultRuntimeObject)

    at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String
configKey)

    at
System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
sectionName)

    at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
sectionName)

    at Castle.Core.Resource.ConfigResource..ctor(String sectionName) in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Core\src\Castle.Core\Core\Resource\ConfigResource.cs:line
44

    at Castle.Core.Resource.ConfigResource..ctor() in e:\OSS.Code\Castle.Core\src\Castle.Core\Core\Resource\ConfigResource.cs:line
32

    at
OurNamespace.DependencyInjection.ApplicationStartupTask.CreateDependencyResolver()
in
OurSolution.VS2010Clean\OurAssembly\DependencyInjection\ApplicationStartupTask.cs:line
70

    at
OurAssembly.DependencyInjection.ApplicationStartupTask.Execute(IDataConfiguration
dataConfiguration) in
OurSolution.VS2010Clean\OurAssembly\DependencyInjection\ApplicationStartupTask.cs:line
46

    at OurProgram.Startup() in OurSolution.VS2010Clean\OurApp\Program.cs:line 83

    at OurApp.Program.Main() in OurSolution.VS2010Clean\OurApp\Program.cs:line 37
```

We did some hunting around but were saddened to see someone had said it was a known .NET 4 bug.

Does anyone know anything about this?

Many thanks for any input
Cheers
Colin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you put the Windsor config in a separate file and try to grab it via

```
container.Install(Configuration.FromXml(new UncResource("your UNC path"))):
```

Comment: Thanks for this Krzysztof, we used a combination of your answer plus the information here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/1e14f665-10a3-426b-a75d-4e66354c5522